# LoadError in ruby when open the bundle exec rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got a problem that when I typing the "br c"(short cut for running bundle exec c), it gave me the error below.

```
ependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
    from /Users/johnhenry/valcuqw/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/johnhenry/valcuqw/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/johnhenry/valcuqw/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/johnhenry/valcuqw/vendor/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.5.6/lib/nokogiri.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/johnhenry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/johnhenry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/johnhenry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/johnhenry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/johnhenry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/johnhenry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/johnhenry/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/johnhenry/valcuqw/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/johnhenry/valcuqw/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Users/johnhenry/valcuqw/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:14:in `require'
    from script/rails:14:in `<main>'
```

Can someone give me a hand on this?

Comment: You've asked nine questions and none of them have had any answers satisfactory of an accept? No thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your app requires nokogiri but you didn't put nokogiri in the Gemfile.

Comment: I just open the gemfile, it has nokogiri. It showed:   gem 'nokogiri', '1.5.6'